# JQuery Script not changing visibility of div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tumblr

Basically, I would like to show `#pagebox` when #about is clicked. At the minute `#about` is a link, I don't know if this affects anything.

The CSS code for `#pagebox` (`#about` doesn't have any)

```
#pagebox{
z-index:99;
background-color:white;
position:fixed;
width:700px;
margin-left:-350px;
margin-top:-300px;
top:50%;
left:50%;
height:600px;
visibility:hidden;
}
```

and this is the script I used (from another questions answer):

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#about').on('click', function(){
    $('#pagebox').show();
});
</script>
```

By the way, I don't know if this makes any difference but I'm coding on Tumblr. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Can we see the HTML ? What type of link it is ?

Comment: You code doesn't compile. It's missing });

Comment: Peter, you may benefit from watching a few of Alex Garret's FREE ten-minute coding tutorials on [thenewboston.com](http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=11) and [phpAcademy.org](http://phpacademy.org/) - also [some on jQuery](http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=32)

Answer (score 1):

You must use display:none; not visibility:hidden; here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/mMkNU/)

**CSS**

```
#pagebox{
  z-index:99;
  background-color:white;
  position:fixed;
  width:700px;
  margin-left:-350px;
  margin-top:-300px;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  height:600px;
  display: none;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
  $('#about').on('click', function(){
    $('#pagebox').show('slow');
  });
});
```

or if you want on/off switch

```
$(function() {
  $('#about').on('click', function(){
    $('#pagebox').toggle('slow');
  });
});
```

Comment: And also remember to include `});` at the end of your script, as dystroy said in his answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I've tried doing this in the form of `<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(function() {
  $('#about').on('click', function(){
    $('#pagebox').show('slow');
  });
});
});
</script>`
and
    `<a href="#" id="about" class = "navlink">About</a>`
but it still doesn't seem to work as you can see from www.hugowolfdesigns.tumblr.com

Comment: Try this `<script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function() { $('#about').on('click', function() { $('#pagebox').show('slow'); }); }); </script>` and if you'r using HTML5 you can write just `<script>` instead of `<script type="text/javascript">`

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work, I wonder if it's anything to do with Tumblr. I've tried other pieces of script and they don't seem to work either

Comment: Ok, I see your code, you must put script on the bottom just before `</body>` tag and please don't use inline CSS in HTML5 ;) also this script `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://assets.tumblr.com/assets/scripts/tumblelog.js?_v=29c08ccdf1ae500e1f96d970dba08a58"></script>` too must be put before mentioned tag.

Comment: What should I put instead of inline? And it still doesn't work I don't think, have I done it right?

Comment: You forgot to delete the script on the top, and put script a little lower, after iframe or just before `</body>` tag. and put script like this `<script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function() { $('#about').on('click', function() { $('#pagebox').show('slow'); }); }); </script>` without source.

Comment: I'm watching your code and I don't know if it's Tumblr or what but you have two doctypes, `<!DOCTYPE html>` , `<head>` is not closed with `</head>` closing tag etc. About CSS you can contact me on email ;)

Comment: Sorry, this is me being completely new to coding but could you please elaborate? Sorry, what do you mean by iframe and where exactly should I put the code? Thank you so much

Comment: Sorry, can't help you thru comments, I'll fix your entire code and I'll post it as answer here. Just a little later...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I fixed your HTML5 errors, duplicate id's, added alt atributes to images, charset, fixed doctype, closed `<head>` and bunch of unclosed links but you still have some inline CSS, work on that, please contact me on email milan@mdesdev.net, source is a little big to post it here.